# Display wait cursor as page element

Tags: javascript, html, operating-system, cursor, detection

I'd like to display the "wait cursor" for the user's operating system as a static element of my webpage.  For instance, for Windows 7, I'd like to put this animation at a particular location on the page:

[image]

Is there a way to choose the animation based on the user's operating system, rather than using a single GIF like the one above for all operating systems?

Note: I don't want to change the user's actual cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Navigator object

```
    if(navigator.platform  == "Win32"){ //for windows
    ///Codez
    }
```

> platform is a string with one of the following values: "Win32", "Linux
>   i686", "MacPPC", "MacIntel", or other.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.navigator.platform)

Comment: This isn't a perfect solution since it requires finding or creating a cursor animation for each operating system type, and doesn't distinguish between OS versions with different cursors.  However, there may not be a better solution.

Comment: I was thinking about this actually. Use css classes for better performance!